# Creating NSInteger category

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, categories, nsinteger

When trying to create a category for NSInteger, the compiler complains that it "Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSInteger'". Is it not possible to create an NSInteger category?

A simple test will show the compiler error:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSInteger (NSInteger_Extensions)

-(NSInteger)simpleTest;

@end



#import "NSInteger_Extensions.h"

@implementation NSInteger (NSInteger_Extensions)

-(NSInteger)simpleTest {
    return self + 5;
}

@end
```

Should this be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSinteger is not an interface. So it's not possible.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

From the link above:

```
Used to describe an integer.

#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

**PS:**
But you can make a category of `NSNumber`. I think it's the thing you want to do

Comment: Doh! Thanks. What a fool I am.

Comment: Ah - - now that's a good point. I was literally just about to write a function that takes my int, does it's work and returns it but a NSNumber category is actually a little more useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: You probably really do not want to add methods to `NSNumber`.  If you really think you do, then make sure you prefix 'em with something unique;  `-hooli_myMagicMethod`.

Answer (score 6):

`NSInteger` is simply a typedef for `int`, a primitive type. Since it's not an object, you won't be able to add a category to it.

You could instead add this to `NSNumber` or `NSValue`.

Comment: I echo my statement to Andrew.. Doh!